# Debug vs Trace in C#

Tags: c#, debugging

As I understand statements like `Debug.WriteLine()` will not stay in the code in the Release build. On the other hand `Trace.WriteLine()` will stay in the code in the Release build.
What is controling this behaviour? Does the C# compiler ignores everything from the `System.Diagnostics.Debug` class when the `DEBUG` is defined?

I am just trying to understand the internals of C# and just curious.

Comment: Tip: One way to discover answers to this kind of thing on your own is to view such methods in Red Gate's [.Net Reflector](http://reflector.red-gate.com/download.aspx).  I suppose you could also download the Framework source.  Note that .Net Reflector will stop being free very soon.  It is an incredibly useful tool, so I recommend downloading it now.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These methods use the [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx) to designate when they should be included.

When `DEBUG` is specified as a `#define`, via [the command line](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0feaad6z%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) or the system environment (`set DEBUG = 1` in the shell), a method marked with `[Conditional("DEBUG")]` will be included by the compiler. When `DEBUG` is not included, those methods and any calls to them will be omitted. You can use this mechanism yourself to include methods under certain circumstances and it is also used to control the `Trace` calls like `Trace.WriteLine` (this uses the `TRACE` define).

Answer (score 5):

This is due to [`ConditionalAttribute`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.conditionalattribute.aspx); the compiler ignores calls to methods marked as conditional unless that symbol is defined.

You can have your own:

```
[Conditional("BLUE")]
void Bar() {...}
```

which will only be called when BLUE is defined.

Note that there are some restrictions, to make "definite assignment" work:

- no return value
- no out parameters

(the same restrictions apply to `partial` methods for similar reasons)